# Convergence of GANs

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum

The original paper, [*Generative Adversarial Nets*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661) (Goodfellow & al., $2014$), states in section $4.2$:

> The subderivatives of a supremum of convex functions include the derivative of the function at the point where the maximum is attained.

I am not able to understand this statement. Can someone please point me to a mathematical proof or representation behind this concept?

Comment: The authors give a pretty clear explanation of the statement in the next sentence of the proof.  Are you saying that you don't understand the statement or that you don't think it's correct?  Are you familiar with concept of the subgradient?

Comment: I read about subgradients, but I will have to say that my concepts there are rusty. Also, I am not questioning the correctness of the statement, it's just that I am not able to understand why this result will hold. If you can point me to a good resource, it will really be very helpful!! Thanks.

Comment: I tried adding subderivative as a tag, but that requires me to have 1000 points. I have added subgradient as a tag now.

Comment: Your question really has nothing to do with GANs but is a more basic questino about the subdifferential in convex analysis.  I'd suggest editing the title of the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$f(x)=\sup_{\alpha} f_{\alpha}(x)$

where the functions $f_{\alpha}$ are convex on some convex domain $D$.  It's a standard theorem that $f$ is convex on $D$.

Suppose that at a particular point $x$ in $D$,

$\beta= \arg \sup_{\alpha} f_{\alpha}(x)$.

Then

$f(x)=f_{\beta}(x)$.

Let $g$ be any subgradient of $f_{\beta}(x)$.  That is, $g \in \partial f_{\beta}(x)$.  By the definition of the subdifferential,

$f_{\beta}(y) \geq f_{\beta}(x) + g^{T}(y-x)$

for all $y$ in $D$.

Since $f(y) \geq f_{\beta}(y)$ for all $y$ in $D$,

$f(y) \geq f(x) + g^{T}(y-x)$

for all $y$ in $D$.  Thus $g \in \partial f(x)$.

Since this holds for any subgradient $g$ in $\partial f_{\beta}(x)$, 
$\partial f_{\beta}(x) \subseteq \partial f(x)$.

Note that the authors of this paper have used somewhat inconsistent notation- they write that $\partial f_{\beta}(x) \in \partial f(x)$, but 
in fact the subdifferential of $f_{\beta}$ is a *subset* of the subdifferential of $f(x)$.

Comment: By $\partial f_\beta(x) \subseteq \partial f(x)$ you mean that this equation holds for that specific point $x$, for which we defined our $\beta$, right? In this case, can it be, that $\partial f_\beta(x) \subsetneq \partial f(x)$? I mean, our $f(x)$ under the hood would use the same $\alpha$ parameter as $f_\beta(x)$ does, so they will be identical at our chosen point $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a geometric view of Brian's answer:

Let $\psi(x) = \sup_\alpha f_\alpha(x)$ and suppose $x$ and $\beta$ are such
that $\psi(x) = f_\beta(x)$.

Since $\operatorname{epi} \psi = \cap_\alpha \operatorname{epi}f_\alpha \subset \operatorname{epi}f_\beta$, we
see that any supporting hyperplane to $\operatorname{epi}f_\beta$ at
$x$ (that is, that contains the epigraph 'above' and passes through
$(x,f_\beta(x))$ must also be a supporting hyperplane to
$\operatorname{epi} \psi$.

In particular, $\partial f_\beta(x) \subset \partial \psi (x)$.

To obtain some intuition, look at $\psi(x) = \max(x,-x)$ at
the point $x=0$.